# Kinetic Fokker-Planck Equation vs Kramers Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, kinematics

Is there any difference between the Kinetic Fokker-Planck Equation and Kramers Equation ? I have seen them both used as a name for the Kolmogorov forward equation describing the time evolution for the distribution of the velocity and position of a particle (e.g living in some solvent).

Does the different choice in name have any meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are several stochastic process with several different names. Maybe, as you said, the Kinetic Fokker-Planck Equation is just the Kramers equation, which is basically a Brownian particle in the phase space, i.e, in the space of position $X$ and momentum $P$. In this equation, the kinetic term is taken into account, which is the first term in the following PDE:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = -\frac{P}{M}\left[\frac{\partial  \rho}{\partial X}\right]+ \gamma\left[\frac{\partial  \left(P\rho\right)}{\partial P}\right]  +D\left[\frac{\partial^2  \rho}{\partial P^2}\right].
\end{align}

For example, take a look in the following reference eq. 1.1) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.05994.pdf